# JSP servlet making a POST request to third party page

Tags: jsp, servlets, post

I'm currently working on a school project, where I have to make a front-end for a cloud based shop. All stock-keeping, userinfo and stuff is at a third party webpage, lets call it www.cloud.com.

To check for a user in the database, I have to do a POST request to www.cloud.com/login with an xml with the username and password in the body of the request. Then it will respond with an xml containing the LoginResponse, and then my servlet has to process that response to see if it was successfull.

After reading this - **http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200603/Journal200603.jsp#a5** I have a pretty good idea of how to design the system, but I'm not very good at JSP.

So my question is, how do I make my servlet do a POST request to the third party page?

I have searched around the web and found multiple posts about this. From what I've read, it is apparently impossible to do a regular POST request from a servlet. I saw a work around, where you manually send the whole HTTP message, but there has to be a better way to do it.

I think that I'm supposed to make a form on the .jsp page, doing a POST action on the servlet, which should call the doPost() method on the servlet. Then I should redirect this request to www.cloud.com/login with the correct body. But then I dont understand how I can intercept the response, so my servlet can check if the login was successfull.

Well, I hope it makes sense for you. Thanks for your help.

/Morten

Comment: You don't "intercept the response", you make the request in the servlet, process the response in the servlet, and pass whatever you need into the request for the JSP you forward to from the servlet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)